# Valid inference or not?

Tags: logic

(For some reason I can't write at the bottom).

(1) For all real numbers $x$, either $p(x)$ or $q(x)$.

(2) $a$ is a real number.

(3) [Not sure I understand. Some help would be appreciated.]

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, p(x) ∨ q(x) $$

$$ a \in \mathbb{R} $$

$$ q(a) \to r(a) $$

Therefore $p(a) ∨ r(a)$.

Comment: Use an extra Enter (carriage return) to format text on separated lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\forall x\in\mathbb R: p(x)\vee q(x)$ and $a\in\mathbb R$, you know that $p(a)\vee q(a)$. Next, you separate the cases. You know that $p(a)\vee q(a)$, meaning either $p(a)$ or $q(a)$ is true

1. if $q(a)$ is true, then you can deduce from $p(a)$ and $p(a)\implies r(a)$ that $r(a)$ is true, and if $r(a)$ is true, so is $p(a)\vee r(a)$
2. if $p(a)$ is true, then $p(a)\vee r(a)$ is also true.

In both cases, you can show that $p(a)\vee r(a)$ is true, so $p(a)\vee r(a)$ is true in general. This type of proof is also known as disjunction elimination:

> If $p\vee q$ and $p\implies x$ and $q\implies x$, then $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are your sure? the statement (3) states that $q(a)\to r(a)$. Also, I understand that $q\to r$ does not imply that $\neg q\to r$

Comment: @cjferes The statement (3) states that $q(a)\implies r(a)$, and (1) and (2) together tell us that $q(a)\vee p(a)$ is true. Now, if $p(a)$ is true, $p(a)\vee r(a)$ is true. If $q(a)$ is true, then from $q(a)\implies r(a)$, we know that $r(a)$ is true, so $p(a)\vee r(a)$ is also true. Which part of this confuzes you?

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I got confused in the process but I understand now.